# Copy perl modules to other machines

Tags: linux, perl, dbi

I have to use a Perl script on different (linux based) Database machines with the DBI module to connect. The oracle drivers are installed, too.

Perl and all the modules are only installed on my 'home' machine, it's not possible on the others. So i tried to copy the modules from the working machine to a DB machine.

I get following error:

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Unable to get DBI state function. DBI not loaded. at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 223.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 3.
```

My modules are installed with cpanmini, how can i find out which modules to copy for my script? I think there are dependencies which i don't recognize?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to copy modules from one machine to another. What if your module or its dependencies are written partially in C (XS)?

If you can't use `cpan` on other machine then download the module and its dependencies from https://metacpan.org and install them manually.

See:

- [Why can't I simply copy installed Perl modules to other machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682608/why-cant-i-simply-copy-installed-perl-modules-to-other-machines)
- [Manual installation of a Perl Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541019/manual-installation-of-a-perl-module)

Comment: yeah, i read these topics and think i just need to find another way, because manually installing isn't possible - we got no connection to the internet at all. But i'm aware now, that just copying modules isn't that easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered elsewhere. Please see

- [Package all Perl module dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604150/package-all-perl-module-dependencies)
- [Install Perl modules with lots of dependencies on a machine without CPAN network access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207800/install-perl-modules-with-lots-of-dependencies-on-a-machine-without-cpan-network)